# how to keep multiplying a number until you reach a specific point in python?

Tags: python, loops, multiplication

I am just beginning python, and I have tried to look up different ways. I know you can add the result with += but that doesn't work with multiplication. I know this is ALL wrong but my code so far is:

Q6=2

while x < 50:
result = x * 2
print(result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `*=` if you want to both assign and multiply to a function in one operation, in fact this same pattern exists for most operators in python (e.g. `/=`, `-=`, `<<=`)

What you need to do here is actually change the value of `Q6` as loop goes on, like this:

```
Q6 = 2
while (Q6 < 50):
    print(Q6)
    Q6 *= 2
```

Because since every number is double the one before, you can just replace Q6 with the previous number

Comment: OMG. I tried the *= because it made the most sense to me at first but I kept getting an error. It was probably something else I did.  THank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function with:

```
def question6(start, limit):
   
   value = start
   while value<limit:
      print(value)
      value*=2 #It does work!

question6(2,50)
```

I suggest reading the introductory tutorials: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Comment: thank you so much. every time i tried to use *= I was getting an error. I will check out the reading because the videos I watched doesn't work.